# Count number of times app has been launched using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to count the number of times my iOS application has been launched using Swift.

I would then like to take the number and display it using `NSLog` each time.

Comment: don't use `NSLog` in Swift, rather use `print()` and `println()`

Comment: Out of curiosity, how come?

Comment: nburk's comment was reasonable when written, but I Am From The Future and here we have oslog() (Unified Logging) as the current best practice for logging.

[Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging)

[OSLog](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/oslog)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add this in `AppDelegate` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.

**Swift 3 and Swift 4:**

```
// get current number of times app has been launched
let currentCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "launchCount")

// increment received number by one
UserDefaults.standard.set(currentCount+1, forKey:"launchCount")
```

**Swift 2:**

```
// get current number of times app has been launched
let currentCount = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("launchCount")

// increment received number by one
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(currentCount+1, forKey:"launchCount")
```

---

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize) there's no more need to call:

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

> Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; this method is *unnecessary* and *shouldn't be used*.

Comment: I get an error using the `.setInteger` as I don't think it accepts `currentCount+=1` as an argument.

Comment: change `currentCount+=1` to `currentCount+1` and it should work! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed it to `currentCount++` but had no luck. `currentCount+1` does the trick.

Comment: If you are looking for how many times user has launched the app this is NOT what you want to do. the applicationDidFinishLaunching will be called by the system too without user interaction. see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html

Comment: Not sure if it matters to you but someone with an unlocked phone could be able to change this number if you store it in user defaults.  I would use core data.

Comment: You don't need to and shouldn't call synchronize anymore

Answer (score 2):

You can store a int to NSUserDefaults.

Every time when you load the app, you can increase the number and save it again.

Add this logic in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Hope this helps.