# How can I access the number of times other apps installed in my iPhone / iPad have been launched?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Does the iOS' internal system keep track what apps have been launched including the number of times they have been launched since they're installed? I want to make an app that lists apps based on how often they're used.

Comment: better go for analytics for your concept

Comment: For your own app see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966810/count-number-of-times-app-has-been-launched-using-swift. I very much doubt that you can get that information for other apps.

Comment: You cannot do this for other Apps. Maybe you need to make an SDK and ask all other developers to integrate it with their Apps

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you can keep track of how many times app launched with method

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

in AppDelegate.m file.

You can also check how many times application comes into foreground from background via

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

in same AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: What I meant was not *my* app but instead, my app wants to read how many times *other* apps have been launched. I should make the subject clearer.